# FindElement(By.Id) not working in a For Loop

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

I am testing Salesforce pages using C# on VS 2019.  I wrote a for loop that clicks on every contact in this table, goes to Contact Details , does some processing, and then goes back to the Contacts page, and processes the next Contact and so on.

[image]

```
// wait until the Contacts table is visible
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='brandBand_1']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody//tr/td[1]")));

    // loop through the contacts table and validate a contacts's  mailing address against the account's shipping address
   var rows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='brandBand_1']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody//tr/td[1]"));

            for (int i = 1; i <= rows.Count; i++)
            {

                IWebElement cell = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='brandBand_1']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/th/span/a"));
                Console.WriteLine("cell text =" + cell.Text);
                cell.Click();   

                // validate the contact mailing address information
                ValidateContactInfo(i);

                // go back to the contacts page
                driver.Navigate().Back();
            }
```

I want the code to click on the Details tab on the Contact Detail page

[image]

Details tab's HTML is as follows

```
 < a data - tab - value = "detailTab" data - label = "Details" role = "tab" href = "javascript:void(0)" tabindex = "-1" aria - selected = "false" 
    class="slds-tabs_default__link" id="detailTab__item" aria-controls="tab-9">Details</a>
```

Searching for the Details tab by Id  (detailTab__item)

```
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
    wait.Until((driver => (driver.FindElement(By.Id("detailTab__item")));

    IWebElement detailsTab = driver.FindElement((By.Id("detailTab__item")));

    detailsTab.Click();
```

returns

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 30 seconds
      ----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"css selector","selector":"#detailTab__item\'"}
          (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

I don't even understand why it's searching by css selector when I told it to search by Id????

Searching by css selector fails too

```
//   copy selector -> # detailTab__item

     wait.Until((driver => (driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#detailTab__item")));
     IWebElement detailsTab = driver.FindElement((By.CssSelector("#detailTab__item")));
```

ditto for searchinng by xpath

```
 wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='detailTab__item']")));
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='detailTab__item']")).Click();
```

I can only find the Details tab if I search by the full XPath, but the problem with that is, that value changes for each Contact ( James Bean , Anna Fields etc..)

How can I search by the same Id or Xpath when in a for loop?

---

Here is the html of the Details tab

[image]

and the full XPath of the Details tab

```
/ html / body / div[4] / div[1] / section / div / div / div[1] / div[3] / div / one - record - home - flexipage2 / forcegenerated - flexipage_contact_rec_l_contact__view_js / flexipage - record - page - decorator / div / slot / flexipage - record - home - template - desktop2 / div / div[2] / div[1] / slot / slot / flexipage - component2 / force - progressive - renderer / slot / slot / flexipage - tabset2 / div / lightning - tabset / div / lightning - tab - bar / ul / li[2] / a
```

Comment: Check element is present inside an iframe?

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the elements at the end of my question. I don't see any ifrrames. Salesforce has custom tags <lightning-tabset> and <lightning-tab-bar>. Other than that, lots of <div> and <li> elements.

Comment: Can you try the below xpath : `wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@role='tablist']//li[@title='Details']/a")));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@role='tablist']//li[@title='Details']/a")).Click();`

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: The problem is when I bring up the page by itself , this code works finr WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement detailsTab = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='detailTab__item']")));
            detailsTab.Click();

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the page in the For loop. This is the same solution for testing it with UFT)

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= rows.Count; i++)
               {

                // refresh the page or selenium won't be able to recognize the elements
                if (i > 1)
                {
                     driver.Navigate().Refresh();

                    wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
                }

                IWebElement cell = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='brandBand_1']/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/th/span/a"));

                cell.Click();


                // validate the contact mailing address information
                ValidateContactInfo(i);

                // go back to the contacts page
                driver.Navigate().Back();
            }
-----------------------------

and in ValidateContactInfo, refresh it as well

 // wait until the page loads
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));


            driver.Navigate().Refresh();

            wait.Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```